# C++ | List iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, list, listiterator

I am trying to iterate through a list and then, if the object's plate number matches the one given through the parameters, and if the toll (calculated in toll()) is less than or equal to the given cents, remove/erase the object from the list. I keep getting the error that the list iterator cannot be incremented and I'm clueless as to how to fix it.

```
void one_time_payment(string& plate_number, int cents) {
    // TODO: REWRITE THIS FUNCTION
    std::list<LicenseTrip>:: iterator it;
    for (it = listLicense.begin(); it != listLicense.end(); std::advance(it, 1)) {
        if (it->plate_number().compare(plate_number) == 0) {
            cout << "Matching Plate Found" << endl;
            if (it->toll() <= cents) {
                cout << "Can be paid" << endl;
                it = listLicense.erase(it); //Error: list iterator cannot be incremented
            }   
        }
    }
    cout << "End of Iterator" << endl;
}
```

Comment: replace `it = listLicense.erase(it);` with `listLicense.erase(it);`

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce with GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4ADAdPjUCnV3cthh). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with gcc either. Additionally, there is a bad bug in the code. If the "if" condition returns true, this results in undefined behavior. In that case, erase() will return end(), this will be assigned to `it`, and the loop iteration increments `it` again. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code compiles good with clang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I'm guessing, not a compile error but rather an assertion that triggered. You have a bug!

Let's say you're on the last element, and all your conditions apply. So we do:

```
it = listLicense.erase(it);
```

Now, `it` is `end()`. But right after that, at the end of the body of the for loop, we advance `it`! This is undefined behavior! Hence: list iterator cannot be incremented.

To help us write this correctly, there is a [`list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove):

```
listLicense.remove_if([&](const LicenseTrip& trip){
    return trip.plate_number() == plate_number &&
        trip.toll() <= cents;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

So, as Barry explained, the problem that was causing the failed assertion was that the iterator would attempt to advance `it` beyond `end()` which would give undefined behavior. In my case, the `it` would only be needed once (only used to locate a `LicenseTrip` with a matching `plate_number`), so it sufficed to put a `break;` after the `listLicense.erase(it)`. The final working code is as follows:

```
 void one_time_payment(string& plate_number, int cents) {
        std::list<LicenseTrip>:: iterator it;
        for (it = listLicense.begin(); (it != listLicense.end()) ; std::advance(it, 1)) {
            if (it->plate_number().compare(plate_number) == 0 && it->toll() <= cents)
                if (it->toll() <= cents) {
                    listLicense.erase(it);
                    break;  
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You redundantly test `it->toll() <= cents)` a second time; and `std::advance(int, 1);` could be replaced by `++it`.